# config.json vs. config.js | what is global-config.js | view server configuration in loopback app?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

1. What is the difference between `config.json` and `config.js`? Do I have to utilize both? When do I need to use one or the other? (https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Environment-specific+configuration#Environment-specificconfiguration-Example)
2. What is `global-config.js`? It is present in Loopback example app (https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-offline-sync/blob/master/global-config.js) but there is no any info about it in docs (https://docs.strongloop.com/dosearchsite.action?queryString=%22global-config.js%22). Why do they invent some third layer for app configuration?
3. How to see full config in runtime? Does it have some code like this?

   `console.log(app.getFullConfig())`

Answer (score 2):

Answering one-by-one:

1. The difference between `config.json` and `config.js` is `config.json` is used to specify server configuration like `host`, `port` etc. Whereas `config.js` is used to override these configuration, if required. For eg.

   If you want to change port number based on country, then you can override this in `config.js` where you can see from which country **loopback app** is being access and change port number based on that.
2. `global-config.js` recides outside `server/` folder. i.e it can be used by many **loopback app**'s `server/` folder. Therefore, the name - `global-config.js`.
3. LoopBack is made on top of Express. Therefore, you can use this option while starting your application.

   `DEBUG=express:application node .`

Answer (score 2):

1. It's useful to know that loopback can use multiple config files for
   different environments. So you might have `config.json` for
   development, and `config.production.json` for production, perhaps
   with the `production.json` config turning off the API explorer.
   Loopback is clever enough to look at your environment variable to
   work out which one to use.

   As well as this, you **can** use .js config files as a *further* override,    which as you would expect allows for some actual code to be run. For
   instance I have a `datasources.json` with my local database
   connection information and a  `datasources.production.js` file which
   looks like a bit like this:

   ```
   var dbhost = process.env.DB_HOST,
         dbname = process.env.DB_NAME,
         dbusername = dbname,
         dbpassword = process.env.DB_PASSWORD;

    module.exports = {
         "db": {
           "host": dbhost,
           "port": 5432,
           "database": dbname,
           "username": dbusername,
           "password": dbpassword,
           "name": "db",
           "connector": "postgresql"
         }
     }
   ```

   As you can see I'm able to use environment variables to store db
   connection details, which I wouldn't want stored in a file (because
   I'm using a public github repo).
2. `global-config.js` is specific to the project which you have linked
   to. It is a Universal Javascript app, so the
       author is using this file to share configuration between the server
       and client code. You can see how he uses it by [searching the repo
       for 'global-config'](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-offline-sync/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=global-config) - it's another good example of why you might
       use a .js config file though, as his `config.local.js` uses code to access configuration in `global-config.js` to override `config.json`, when the app is running locally.
3. As you can see, configuration can be dealt with in a multitude of ways depending on your requirements, so I don't think there is a way of writing out every single config value in use, without writing a custom bit of code.